# ggplot: Adding a plot outline with the axis ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, axis, xticks

I'm trying to create plots where the x-axis ALSO appears above the plot as well as the y-axis to the right of the plot. Both should contain the same ticks as the normal axis, but NOT the axis text. This should result in a "box" with helpful tick-marks around the plot. I would also like to have smaller ticks in-between my major ticks (that are labelled) that do not have a label. Here is a figure I made:

[image: Plot as it is now]

I also drew in pink what I would like to achieve in R:

[image: Plot as I would like it]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAn03.jpg)

My code for this plot:

```
p <- p + xlab("") + ylab("") + theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "cm"), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 30, hjust=1)) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=35, hjust = 1), strip.text = element_text(size=35), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 40), legend.text = element_text(size=30), axis.title.x = element_text(size=40), legend.title = element_text(size=45)) 
p <- p + theme(text = element_text(family = "Helvetica")) + scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-0.5, 25), breaks = c(0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 24))  + theme(legend.background = element_rect(color = "black", linetype = "solid")) + scale_colour_manual(values = cbpallette)
p <- p + theme(legend.key.size = unit(2.5, "cm")) + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = .5, unit = "cm")), axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = .5, unit = "cm")))
p
```

*** Edit ***
Here is updated code, using Stefans advise. The figure looks like so, the ticks are there, the axis are missing:

[image: updated figure]

```
p <- p + xlab("") + ylab("") + theme(legend.position = "none") + theme(axis.ticks.length = unit(-0.25, "cm"), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 30, hjust=1)) + theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size=35, hjust = 1, angle=45), strip.text = element_text(size=35), axis.title.y = element_text(size = 40), legend.text = element_text(size=30), axis.title.x = element_text(size=40)) 
p <- p + theme(text = element_text(family = "Helvetica"))  + scale_colour_manual(values = cbpallette)
p <- p + theme(axis.text.x = element_text(margin = margin(t = .5, unit = "cm")), axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = .5, unit = "cm"))) 
p
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could duplicate the axes using argument `sec.axis = dup_axis()` for both scales like so:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(hp, mpg)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_x_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL)) +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = dup_axis(name = NULL, labels = NULL))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, thanks. I have found that already but now the top axis (duplicated x-axis) and right axis (duplicated y-axis) have labels and text. I would like those to only contain the ticks NOT the text. Is this possible?

Comment: Yep. Of course. `labels=NULL`. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Thanks Stefan, I run into a new problem using your method, however, I think you will immediately see what I did wrong. I get the ticks, I do not get the axis now (they seem to fall outside the plot). I edited my original post with the new code + image so you can see what I mean.

Comment: So this is the most tricky part. (: There is probably a cleaner solution. But as a workaround ... Set `name = ""` inside `dup_axis`. This will add some space to the top and  the right.

Comment: Thank you Stefan, that works perfectly, very smart solution! Thanks for your help!